# What could happen if a 240 stove cord was improperly installed and then stove was plugged in to the receptacle?

Tags: installation, appliances, receptacle, stove, 240v

I think my new stove cord was installed incorrectly — after being plugged in we heard a ((whooooaamp)) sound and all the lights in the house flickered, now none of my 220 appliances will work correctly. The other appliances weren't plugged in when this happened, except the water heater which I can't get to turn on either. The time and displays on my stove come on but the stove top & oven won't do anything, my dryer displays come on, but when I push the start cycle button the display flickers and then everything shuts off, as if everything isn't getting enough power to fully work. What could have happened? and what can I do now?

Comment: Sounds like you lost half your service power. 
Who did the work?
I would call an electrician immediately to check.

Comment: I agree, it sure sounds like you may have lost one leg of the 220VAC supply. Testing for the root cause requires using a volt meter and a good understanding of how the circuit should work so the problem can be diagnosed. From the info given, the problem could be anything from a bad connection, faulty breaker or even a supply problem. If you do not have the tools or experience, do not attempt to fix this yourself, call an electrician.  Be safe, not sorry.

Comment: @Samantha: It sounds very unusual to me to have all those appliances on the same circuit.   Do they have separate breakers?   If they don't, that is pretty dangerous to begin with because the breaker would need to be oversized.   If they do have separate breakers, then the problem must be in your breaker panel or on the service side of it.

Comment: The supply to your house is obviously three-phase, which is a combination  of 3 AC supplies, which, when combined form a nice supply (the wavelengths of each ac supply are off-set so that the peak's of each wave follow on continually) -- One of your phases at your main board (outside the house) or Municipal pole has tripped and its causing  havoc with your supply.